# pulp constraint: exactly N in a category, up to X of a second choice, same category

Tags: python, constraints, pulp

I have a problem I'm trying to solve for where I want N players from one team, and up to X players from a second team, but I don't particularly care which team fills those constraints. For example, if N=5 and X=2, I could have 5 from one team and up to 2 from a second, different, team. How would I write such a constraint?

example dataframe:

|  | team | pos | name | ceil | salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | NYY | OF | Aaron Judge | 21.6631 | 6500 |
| 1 | HOU | OF | Yordan Alvarez | 21.6404 | 6100 |
| 2 | ATL | OF | Ronald Acuna Jr. | 21.5363 | 5400 |
| 3 | HOU | OF | Kyle Tucker | 20.0992 | 4700 |
| 4 | TOR | 1B | Vladimir Guerrero Jr. | 20.0722 | 6000 |
| 5 | LAD | SS | Trea Turner | 20.0256 | 5700 |
| 6 | LAD | OF | Mookie Betts | 19.5231 | 6300 |
| 7 | SEA | OF | Julio Rodriguez | 19.3694 | 5200 |
| 8 | MIN | OF | Byron Buxton | 19.3412 | 5600 |
| 9 | LAD | 1B | Freddie Freeman | 19.3393 | 5600 |
| 10 | TOR | OF | George Springer | 19.1429 | 5100 |
| 11 | NYM | OF | Starling Marte | 19.0791 | 5200 |
| 12 | ATL | 1B | Matt Olson | 19.009 | 4800 |
| 13 | ATL | 3B | Austin Riley | 18.9091 | 5200 |
| 14 | SF | OF | Austin Slater | 18.9052 | 3700 |
| 15 | NYM | 1B | Pete Alonso | 18.8921 | 5700 |
| 16 | TEX | OF | Adolis Garcia | 18.7115 | 4200 |
| 17 | TEX | SS | Corey Seager | 18.6957 | 5100 |
| 18 | TOR | OF | Teoscar Hernandez | 18.6834 | 5200 |
| 19 | CWS | 1B | Jose Abreu | 18.497 | 4600 |
| 20 | ATL | SS | Dansby Swanson | 18.4679 | 4900 |
| 21 | TEX | 2B/SS | Marcus Semien | 18.4389 | 4100 |
| 22 | NYY | 1B | Anthony Rizzo | 18.4383 | 5300 |
| 23 | NYY | 2B | Gleyber Torres | 18.39 | 4500 |
| 24 | CHC | C | Willson Contreras | 18.3452 | 5800 |

existing code snippet:

```
        #problem definition
        prob = LpProblem(name="DFS", sense=LpMaximize)
        prob += lpSum(player_vars[i] * slate['ceil'].iloc[i] for i in player_ids), "FPTS"
        
        #salary and total player constraints
        prob += lpSum(player_vars[i] * slate['salary'].iloc[i] for i in player_ids) <= 50000, "Salary"
        prob += lpSum(player_vars[i] for i in player_ids) == 10, "Total Players"
        
        #position constraints
        prob += lpSum(player_vars[i] for i in player_ids if slate['pos'].iloc[i] == 'P') == 2, "Pitcher"
        prob += lpSum([player_vars[i] for i in player_ids if slate['name'].iloc[i] in slate['name'][slate['pos'].str.contains('C')].to_list()]) == 1, "Catcher"
        prob += lpSum([player_vars[i] for i in player_ids if slate['name'].iloc[i] in slate['name'][slate['pos'].str.contains('1B')].to_list()]) == 1, "1B"
        prob += lpSum([player_vars[i] for i in player_ids if slate['name'].iloc[i] in slate['name'][slate['pos'].str.contains('2B')].to_list()]) == 1, "2B"
        prob += lpSum([player_vars[i] for i in player_ids if slate['name'].iloc[i] in slate['name'][slate['pos'].str.contains('3B')].to_list()]) == 1, "3B"
        prob += lpSum([player_vars[i] for i in player_ids if slate['name'].iloc[i] in slate['name'][slate['pos'].str.contains('SS')].to_list()]) == 1, "SS"
        prob += lpSum([player_vars[i] for i in player_ids if slate['name'].iloc[i] in slate['name'][slate['pos'].str.contains('OF')].to_list()]) == 3, "OF"
        
       
        #no opposing pitcher constraint
        for pid in player_ids:
            if slate['pos'].iloc[pid] == 'P':
                prob += lpSum([player_vars[i] for i in player_ids if 
                    slate['team'].iloc[i] == slate['opp'].iloc[pid]] + [9 * player_vars[pid]]) <= 9, "P{pid}".format(pid=pid)

        #three team max constraint
        unique_teams = slate['team'].unique()
        player_in_team = slate['team'].str.get_dummies()        
        team_vars = LpVariable.dicts('team', unique_teams, cat = 'Binary')
        
        for team in unique_teams:
            prob += lpSum([player_in_team[team][i] * player_vars[i] for i in player_ids if slate['pos'].iloc[i] != 'P']) >= team_vars[team], "Team{team}Min".format(team=team)
            
        
        prob += lpSum(team_vars[team] for team in unique_teams) == 3, "3 Teams"
```

Comment: can you clarify your comment about "up to 2 from a second team, but I don't care which team..."  If you are selecting 10 players, and 5 come from 1 team, would it be feasible to select 2 from a second team and 3 from a 3rd team to make the 10?  Or do you mean to say "no more than 2 from any other team?"  Or something else entirely...  That part of the constraint is unclear.

Comment: and for clarity, can you confirm that you do not intend to identify the teams that supply the 5 and other?  Your title says "choice" so I'm just clarifying that you don't really care which team the 5 come from, as long as your final team has 5 from *some* team...

Comment: "Your title says "choice" so I'm just clarifying that you don't really care which team the 5 come from, as long as your final team has 5 from some team" -- exactly this. As long as 5 come from the same team, it doesn't matter which team that is. 

"If you are selecting 10 players, and 5 come from 1 team, would it be feasible to select 2 from a second team and 3 from a 3rd team to make the 10?" 5 from Team 1, up to 2 from Team 2, and the rest can come from any combo of other teams, be that 3 from team 3 or 1 each from teams 3, 4 and 5.

Comment: Ok.  So your 2nd constraint I think can be restated more simply by saying you must pick from at least 3 teams, which is easier to code.

Comment: @AirSquid -- I added in a snippet to the original question for the 2nd constraint (understanding that it's for 3 exactly) I think that will work for that part. 

I'm still stuck on the 5-2 part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would attack this...  In pseudocode....

1. make a set of teams that you can use to index a couple of new variables.
2. Make subsets of your players grouped by team, or use `pandas` data frame filters to limit summations of players to the team of interest.
3. Make 2 new variables, that are binary "indicator" variables, one call it `use5from[team]` and one called `use[team]` to indicate that the team has been used at all.
4. Make appropriate constraints to link those to the selection variables.  Something like:

```
for team in teams:
    5 * use5from[team] <= pulp.lpSum(x[i] for i in team[i])
```

5. And for the other, a constraint to indicate any use...

```
for team in teams:
    use[team] <= pulp.lpSum(x[i] for i in team[I])
```

6. And then make constraints that those two variables sum to over 1 and 3 respectively.

Comment: That did the trick! It was the second variable that was eluding me. Thank you very much.